# console close automatically without showing output

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i am  trying to work on vs,console. when i just write:

```
Console.WriteLine("c#");
```

the console appear just for a second, without output and close automatically. 
but when :

`Console.ReadLine();`

is added to this , it shows the output .

why is this happening with `Console.WriteLine("");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output only appears for a second because that's all your program is doing. When you add `Console.ReadLine();` or `Console.ReadKey();` the console is going to wait for you to press a key before closing it.

You could also try hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. It will add a pause with "Press any key to continue..."

Comment: I see you are new to stack overflow. If you think my answer my answer is the best could you mark it as answer? Thanks